# Як правильно говорити: україномовний чи українськомовний

Tags: вживання-слів

Як правильно говорити: україн**о**мовний чи україн**сько**мовний? В академічному тлумачному словнику (1970—1980) є лише перший варіант - [україномовець](http://sum.in.ua/f/ukrajinomovecj), те ж саме з українською вікіпедією - знайшов лише випадки вживання першого варіанту - "[україномовний](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8#%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D1%96_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8E_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8_(1990_%E2%80%94_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87._2000-%D0%B8%D1%85))". З іншого боку можна знайти й твердження, що правильно використовувати саме варіант "[українськомовний](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-40718117)" (при цьому пол**ьсько**мовний, але англ**о**мовний).

Також якщо проводити аналогію з такими словами як "українофіл", "українофоб" то випливає, що україномовний - "той, що говорить Україною" а не українською.